# Error when ordering grouped bars in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data is in the long format (as required to do the grouped barplot), so that the values for different categories are in one single column. The data is [here](https://ethercalc.org/c3r94glgm9o2).

Now, a standard barplot with ggplot2 orders the bars alphabetically (in my case of country names, from Argentina to Uganda). I want to keep the order of countries as it is in the dataframe. Using the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208679/order-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-graph) (i.e. ussing the `limits=` option inside the `scale_x_discrete` function) I get the following graph:

[image]

My code is this:

```
mydata <- read_excel("WDR2016Fig215.xls", col_names = TRUE) 

y <- mydata$value
x <- mydata$country
z <- mydata$Skill

ggplot(data=mydata, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=z)) + 
            geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), colour="black") + 
            scale_x_discrete(limits=x)
```

The graph is nicely sorted as I want but the x axis is for some reason expanded. Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: Try converting `x` to integers, `x = as.integer(x)`. And `geom_col` is a handy shortcut for `stat = "identity"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this?

```
mydata$country <- factor(mydata$country, levels=unique(mydata$country)[1:30])
ggplot(data=mydata, aes(x=country, y=value, fill=Skill)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), colour="black")
```

Comment: That! What is the explanation?

Comment: I reordered mydata$country factor levels to the desired sequence. For reordering factor levels check here https://www.r-bloggers.com/reorder-factor-levels/ and here http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Changing_the_order_of_levels_of_a_factor/